# How to setup rounded corner menu in joomla

Tags: joomla, rounded-corners

Does anyone know how to setup a round corner menu in joomla? I need each item in the menu to have rounded corner.

Answer (score 0):

Are you having trouble creating the rounded corner images or trouble using them in the template?

I would go to SpiffyBox.com (http://spiffybox.com) or CoolText.com (http://cooltext.com/) to easily generate the buttons or background image you want to use for the menus.

To use your new images in the menu, you will probably have to connect to the website via FTP, upload your images to the correct folder, and then edit the template so that it uses the correct images.

The easiest way to do this is to find the folder on the server where the current menu images are stored, name your new buttons the same names as the ones being used, and upload the new images, overriding the current images with the new ones. Then you won't have to edit the path to the images, the template will automatically display your new ones since they have the same name the old ones did. Of course, before you do override the old images, I would download and save the current images so you have them if the new buttons dont work!

A few things you will need to be careful about are: either the new buttons need to have the exact same dimensions as the current buttons; or (if the new buttons don't have the same dimensions) you will need to edit the menu attributes (height, width, etc.) in your template's stylesheet so that the new buttons display properly without throwing off the whole template.

Hope this helps! let me know if you have questions...